# Security announcement mailing list for Java

Tags: known-vulnerabilities, java, patching, oracle

I didn't find a security announcement mailing list for Java (from Oracle). How to get notified about new Java patches? I am not interested in other Oracle products.

For example Apple provides such a list with signed mails: https://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/security-announce (Security-announce -- Product security notifications and announcements from Apple)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to Oracle's security advisory mailing list by following the instructions at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/securityemail-090378.html.

You should also read http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/alerts-086861.html for more information. In particular, the section relating to third party bulletins.

Comment: thank you. It's a huge privacy issue with Oracle OTN account. They wish to have all my corporate and personal data. They _need_ only email address.

Comment: @fyodor78, that is annoying.  Do what everyone else does, and lie on everything other than the email address.  You can really have fun with it: e.g., I am the CIO for a company that makes over $1 billion in revenue each year and has 3 employees, my main residence is in Antarctica, and I first heard of Oracle through telegram.